# Read a text file from line 0 to 200 then from 400 to 600 then to 800 to 1000 in Python

Tags: python

I have generated a txt file in Python and I want to parse this file retrieving 200 line data groups. I've seen a lot of ways to parse txt files but can't you just iterate through lines like you'd do in JAVA, for instance a thing like :

```
for(int i = 0; i < 200, i++)
```

and then access it by writing `line[i] ...` ?

Comment: You can if you read the contents of the file first (this will give you simple random access).

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to store all the lines in memory, you may want to use something like this:

```
lines = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for i in range(num_rows):
        if i % 400 > 200:
            next(f)
        else:
            line = f.readline()
            lines.append(line.strip())
print(lines)
```

Here I assumed you know the number of lines in the file. You can modify the code and read lines till end of file.

Answer (score 2):

There is a method, `readlines()`, which will read all of the file and return it as a list of lines, which you can then access by index.

Comment: Okay, it seems to work except that when I try to cast a line into an int, for instance 
`a = int(line[157])`
it doesn't work cause the line[157] includes the carriage return I guess

Answer (score 1):

You may do it using `file.readlines()` as:

```
basket_size, jump = 200, 200 

with open('file') as f:  # Open file
    file_content = f.readlines()  # list of all lines
    for i in range(0, len(file_content), basket_size+jump):
        for line in file_content[i:i+basket_size]:
            print line
```

Here:

- **basket_size**: the size of each chunk to print
- **jump**: size of jump, after the chunk

Also check: [Methods for File Objects](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Answer (score 0):

use file.read().splitlines() to read file into list with newlines stripped off

```
with open(r'file.txt') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()
    n=0
    for i in range(len(lines)): # replace range with xrange if use python 2
        if n<200: # needed data 200 lines
            print lines[i]
        elif n == 400-1: # 400 = 200 needed data + 200 skip unwanted data
            n=0 # reset count to 0
            continue
        n+=1
```

if processing large files, recommended to use generator based to be more efficient, modify based on itertools islice method

```
import sys
def slice_xx(iterable, chunk=200, step=200):
    it = iter(range(0, sys.maxint, chunk+step)) # replace range with xrange if use python 2
    nexti = next(it)
    for i, element in enumerate(iterable):
        if nexti <= i < nexti + chunk:
            yield element.rstrip() # perform newline strip off here
        if i == nexti+chunk:
            nexti = next(it)

with open(r'file.txt') as f:
    for i in slice_xx(f):
        print i
```